# Scientist sets up experiment without pre-determining the outcome

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, metaphysics

His theory is that scientists pre-determine the result of experiment by their expectations and thereby influence how the world works. He sets up an experiment with no expectations and when it runs, the world reverts to its true state. Very metaphysical and intriguing. A short story from the 50's or 60's.

Comment: This sort of reminds me to some Stanislaw Lem stories, but doesn't quite match.

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/212224/bishop-berkeleys-ideas-put-to-the-test (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 14):

["The New Reality"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41114), a novelette by [Charles L. Harness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_L._Harness), first published in [*Thrilling Wonder Stories*, December 1950](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61701+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Thrilling_Wonder_Stories_v37n02_1950-12#page/n55/mode/2up).

Adrian Prentiss, "professional ontologist", explains the premise of the story:

> The ontologist continued rapidly. "All of you doubt my sanity. A week ago I would have, too. But since then I've done a great deal of research in the history of science. And I repeat, *the universe is the work of man*. I believe that man began his existence in some incredibly simple world--the original and true *noumenon* of our present universe. And that over the centuries man expanded his little world into its present vastness and incomprehensible intricacy solely by dint of imagination.
> [. . . .]
> "I maintain that their information was substantially accurate. I maintain that at one time in our history the earth was flat—as flat as it is now round, and no one living before the time of Hecataeus, though he might have been equipped with the finest modern instruments, could have proved otherwise. His mind was *conditioned* to a two-dimensional world. Any of us present, if we were transplanted to the world of Hecataeus, could, of course, establish terrestrial sphericity in short order. Our minds have been conditioned to a three-dimensional world. The day may come a few millennia hence when a four-dimensional Terra will be commonplace even to school children; they will have been intuitively conditioned to relativistic concepts." He added slyly: "And the less intelligent of them may attempt to blame our naive three-dimensional planet on our grossly inaccurate instruments, because it will be as plain as day to them that their planet has four dimensions!"
> [. . . .]
> "Look at the evidence. Has it never struck you as odd in how many instances very obvious facts were 'overlooked' until a theory was propounded that required their existence? Take your nuclear building blocks. Protons and electrons were detected physically only after Rutherford had showed they had to exist. And then when Rutherford found that protons and electrons were not enough to build all the atoms of the periodic table, he postulated the neutron, which of course was duly 'discovered' in the Wilson cloud chamber."

The villain of the story, Professor Luce, has constructed a device in his laboratory which which he intends to destroy a photon, thereby destroying the universe as we know it, returning it to its primordial state:

> "Then," said Goring, "assuming, purely for the sake of argument, that man has altered the original *noumena* into our present reality, just what danger do you think Luce represents to that reality? How could he do anything about it, even if he wanted to? Just what is he up to?"
> "Broadly stated," said Prentiss, "Luce intends to destroy the Einsteinian universe."
> Burchard frowned and shook his head. "Not so fast. In the first place, how can anyone presume to destroy this planet, much less the whole universe? And why do you say the 'Einsteinian' universe? The universe by any other name is still the universe, isn't it?"
> "What Dr. Prentiss means," explained E., "is that Luce wants to revise completely and finally our present comprehension of the universe, which presently happens to be the Einsteinian version, in the expectation that the final version would be the true one—and comprehensible only to Luce and perhaps a few other ontologic experts."
> [. . . .]
> "Exactly," said Prentiss. "Instead of a continuum, our 'reality' would become a disconnected melange of three-dimensional objects. Time, if it existed, wouldn't bear any relation to spatial things. Only an ontologic expert might be able to synthesize any sense out of such a 'reality.'"

The ending:

> Meta-universe, by whatever name you called it, was beautiful, like a gorgeous garden. What a pity he must live and die here alone, with nothing but a lot of animals for company. He'd willingly give an arm, or at least a rib, if—
> "Adrian Prentiss! Adrian!"
> He whirled and stared toward the orchard in elated disbelief.
> "E! *E!*."
> She'd got through!
> The whole world, and just the two of them!
> His heart was pounding ecstatically as he began to run lithely upwind.
> And they'd keep it this way, simple and sweet, forever, and their children after them. To hell with science and progress! (Well, within practical limits, of course)
> As he ran, there rippled about his quivering nostrils the seductive scent of apple blossoms.

Comment: Great answer with very little to go on.

Comment: Meet the new reality, same as [the old one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_of_Eden)?